# Stop Linux Terminal from going to new line when pressing enter

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I'm working on a simple Java cypher program. That's why there are strange characters.

I'm attempting to run this command in my Linux Terminal:

```
user@Ubuntu> java code d ÖÝßÛ³eb©«åãáâ¡§ÌÚØ¨¬Ý¢¤¤°kkicÒÒ××â¥¡ÏÛÛÐë`§ÞØÝßòÓ key
```

With this being said, When I press enter this happens:

```
user@Ubuntu> java code d ÖÝßÛ³eb©«åãáâ¡§ÌÚØ¨¬Ý¢¤¤°kkicÒÒ××â¥¡ÏÛÛÐë`§ÞØÝßòÓ key
>
>
>
>
```

A New line appears each time I press enter. How can I just run the command?

Answer (score 6):

This happens because your argument contain a backtick (`` ` ``), which is a special shell character. Try putting your special characters in strong quotes:

```
user@Ubuntu> java code d 'ÖÝßÛ³eb©«åãáâ¡§ÌÚØ¨¬Ý¢¤¤°kkicÒÒ××â¥¡ÏÛÛÐë`§ÞØÝßòÓ' key
```

Single quotes (`'`, distinct from `` ` ``) prevents the shell from trying to interpret your argument.

Comment: Please mark question as answered if you believe it's fixed!